# gitignore for several projects but not for all

Tags: git

Here is how I store my Python projects for which I will like to use the same `gitignore` rules. I use this kind of structure because I have also projects in other programing languages.

```
+ python
    + tools
        + misTool
            * ...
        + orPyste
            * ...
    + math
        + natMath
            * ...
```

In these structure, `misTool`, `orPyste`, `natMath`, ... are independant  projects with heir own repository.

How can I put a `gitignore` file in the folder `python` that can be used for all the projects `misTool`, `orPyste`, `natMath`, ... ?

Comment: If your question was resolved, don't forget to accept an answer..

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `git config --local core.excludesfile path_to_my_gitignore_file` do the job. This must be done when the local git repository is initiated.

Comment: +1 I use that for global and local exclusions, pointing them to some files from https://github.com/github/gitignore

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can directly source ignore rules from an out of repository file every time.

To work around, here is what I would do:

If none of those independent projects have a gitignore file, I would create symlinks to the common `.gitignore` file within each of the project.

Otherwise, if they have gitignore files of their own, I would overwrite the `.git/info/exclude` file within each of the repository, and create a symlink in its place within `.git/info` directory linking to the common ignore file (the common ignore file would then obviously have the name `exclude`).

Answer (score 0):

If the folders you mention are already their own repositories, you'll have an easier time if you just include them into your main project as git submodules.

Comment: Indeed, I really want that each project has its own repository in github.

Comment: Then submodules are the way to go.

Comment: Ok. From github point of view, will all the projects be in their own page ?

Comment: After googling with Git Submodules, some people think that is better to work with Git Subtree. What is your opinion on that ?

Comment: Subtrees are useful if you want to completely embed one project in another.  A submodule lets you chane the sub project and shere the changes with others.  There are cases for both, although some recommendations for subtrees are made because some people think Submodules are _hard_. I've never had any problems with them.